# How to source a file having environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, sh, csh

I have a source file having environment variables (few environmental variables are conditional based as well).
source file is like (filename: global_setup)

```
if( -f /tools/tool/bin) then
    setenv SHELL /bin/csh
endif

setenv LICENCE_FILE 2457@abc
setenv ...........
```

I want to source this file using python script. Code is like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

if os.path.isfile('global_setup'):
    subprocess.call(['/bin/csh', '-c', 'source ~/global_setup'], shell=True)
else:
    print("file not found");
```

But this is not working. Showing error as:

> /home/global_setup: line 53: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Also, I tried to remove this EOF error by changing file format to Unix.
Even it works, i doubt setup will be done in some other terminal as i am using subprocess.call() in python.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcing a file with `subprocess.call()` won't have an effect on the environment variables in Python, since `subprocess` runs, well, a subprocess.

You will need to parse the file yourself if you wish to affect `os.environ` within your Python interpreter.

Since your file is csh-style, the otherwise very nice [`envparse`](https://github.com/rconradharris/envparse) module won't do here.

Something you could do, though, is invoke

```
env = subprocess.check_output(['/bin/csh', '-c', 'source ~/global_setup; printenv'], shell=True)
```

and parse the resulting `env` variable line by line and add the contents into `os.environ`. This way the conditionals within `global_setup` would also work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it this way, you should be doing one of two things:

1. Source your files in the linux shell *before* invoking your script.
2. Convert your file into a `dotenv` file that Python can read using the Python-dotenv module.

Sourcing it before is easier IMO, instead of sourcing it during runtime using subprocess.